# NSURLConnection gives EXC BAD ACCESS when tap on other tab while data loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am getting data from my online server through JSON. I works fine. But when I tap on one tab then another while the data in first tab is loading is first give me a JSON error then if I try to handle it through code at the end of this function it gives  EXC BAD ACCESS error.

I am not sure where I am doing wrong I am not running any thing in background like timers etc

Looking forward to get response from stackoverflow community 
Mani

Answer (score 1):

What class is using the NSURL to fetch the data?  Does it have a reference to your class so it can call back when it's done or when it fails?  When you hit tab, your class if probably being deallocated and then your NSURL class tries to call it, but it's gone.  Try setting up NSZombieEnabled in your executable properties Arguments tab; this should tell you where it's happening and what's going on.