# ASINetworkQueue:trying to perform selector on deallocated delegate

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I am using the sample code from 
https://gist.github.com/150447

when the viewcontroller unloads, im setting the networkqueue to nil, and also calling the reset method.

`[[self networkQueue1] reset]; 

[self setNetworkQueue1:nil];`

but still i get exception as soon as i go back to previous view controller.

*** -[myViewController performSelector:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc1d1bb0

Please suggest whats going wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nil any delegates in the dealloc() method or earlier. Depending on exactly which delegates etc you're setting, something like this should do it:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in [queue operations])
{
    [req cancel];
    [req setDelegate:nil];
}
[queue setDelegate:nil];
```

Basically, you need to make sure the delegate is removed any current request before the delegate is destroyed - this will make sure that a deallocated delegate will never get called.

Comment: I had this same issue, and it is definitely fixed by canceling the request and setting the delegate to nil.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this too, but problem was, I was cancelling operations in (void)viewDidUnload, and I dont know for what reason this method wasn't being called. I just put [networkQueue1 reset];
 [networkQueue1 release]; in dealloc method, and it solved my problem.

Comment: @waheeda : viewDidUnload is called normally when your app gets out of memory. View controllers by default are registered for memory warning notifications, and any view that is not currently being used will be unloaded by the view controller - the viewDidUnload method is there so that you can clean up anything else you would like, to save extra memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post [NSURLConnection gives EXC BAD ACCESS when tap on other tab while data loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029893/nsurlconnection-gives-exc-bad-access-when-tap-on-other-tab-while-data-loading/5031488#5031488)

Basically, an object still has a reference to your view controller (probably so it can do a callback to it), and when you go back to the previous VC, the current VC is being deallocated (as it should.)  You need to find that object, and nill out it's reference to your VC (probably called "delegate" or "callback").
Hope that helps.